# Start outer incrementation value with 0 in the inner cicle - assembly

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, increment

I want to copy a 5x5 matrix of bits to a peripherical. The problem I´m having is that I can´t start the column cicle with the line incrementation variable with 0. In a high-level it would be like this (very simple):

```
for (line=0;line<4;line++)
 for (column=0;column<4;column+++)
```

R2- line

R3- column

```
line_cicle:
CMP R2, 4
JZ end
ADD R2,1
column_cicle:
    ; do stuff that is not depend of the end of a line
    CMP R3, 4
    JZ line_cicle
    ; do stuff that is depend of the end of a line
    ADD R3, 1
    JMP column_cicle
```

That ADD R2,1 is what is messing up, but where do I put it so that it doesn´t start with 1?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/589/loops/1945/for-loop#t=201704251520018615353  (see how `for` can be rewritten by `while`, which should resemble assembly variant more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you're saying/doing with your proposed assembly implementation. Why are you initializing the register to 1 when your loop is supposed to start at 0?

But a for loop nested in another for loop is a relatively simple thing to write, so let's start over and just take things one step at a time, starting from the high-level C code:

```
for (line=0;line<4;line++)
    for (column=0;column<4;column++)
```

Here is the first (outer) for loop:

```
    xor  eax, eax        ; line = 0

.LineLoop:
    ; Do something with line (EAX).
    ; ...

    inc  eax             ; ++line

    cmp  eax, 4
    jb   .LineLoop       ; keep looping if line < 4

; We are now finished with the loop.
```

Now, of course, a compiler wouldn't generate this code. This is a very small loop—it only goes around 4 times—so the overhead of the loop is probably going to be substantial compared to the code that gets executed inside, on each iteration. So a compiler would actually *unroll* the loop 4 times, producing code that is not only faster but more readable. However, I digress…we were writing loops. :-)

We have the outer loop, and we need the inner loop. Of course, the inner loop is basically the same thing as the outer loop, just with a different variable. Here is the inner loop:

```
    xor  edx, edx        ; column = 0

.ColumnLoop:
    ; Do something with column (EDX).
    ; ...

    inc  edx             ; ++column

    cmp  edx, 4
    jb   .ColumnLoop     ; keep looping if column < 4

; We are now finished with the loop.
```

Simple enough, right? I just changed the variable/register and the label name. The last task is to *nest* them. It turns out that is simple, too. The inner loop's code just gets stuck right in the outer loop's code, right there where I said `Do something with line (EAX)`, since the inner loop *is* going to do something with line—it's going to loop through all of the columns associated with that line. It is another copy-paste job:

```
    xor  eax, eax        ; line   = 0
.LineLoop:
    xor  edx, edx        ; column = 0
.ColumnLoop:
    ; Do something with line (EAX) and column (EDX).
    ; ...

    inc  edx             ; ++column
    cmp  edx, 4
    jb   .ColumnLoop     ; keep looping if column < 4

    inc  eax             ; ++line
    cmp  eax, 4
    jb   .LineLoop       ; keep looping if line < 4

; We are now finished with both loops.
```

---

Remember that you can choose different registers for your loop counters. I just arbitrarily chose `EAX` and `EDX`. If you are going to call a function inside the body of the loop that does something with the line and column, and that function expects its parameters to be passed in different registers, then you might as well use *those* registers as your loop counters.

---

Note that there is a slightly more optimal way to write this code that would eliminate the `cmp` instructions. Instead of starting from 0 and counting *up* (which requires us to do a comparison to see if we've reached the end yet), we can start from the end and count *down*. Then, we just take advantage of the fact that the `dec` instruction sets the zero flag (`ZF`) when the result is 0, branching directly on that flag, instead of having to do a comparison. The code is easier to understand than the explanation:

```
    mov  eax, 4          ; line   = 4
.LineLoop:
    mov  edx, 4          ; column = 4
.ColumnLoop:
    ; Do something with line (EAX) and column (EDX).
    ; ...

    dec  edx             ; --column
    jnz  .ColumnLoop     ; keep looping if column > 0

    dec  eax             ; --line
    jnz   .LineLoop       ; keep looping if line > 0

; We are now finished with both loops.
```

The only issue with this is that you are looping *backwards* over the lines and columns. This is usually not a problem, though.